# Javascript Auto Form Filling

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, awesomium

I am trying to autologin into facebook using javascript and iam using awesomium as webcontrol in my c# application which can execute javascripts.i need the right javascript to autofill both textbox and click the login button
URL:https://www.facebook.com/login

```
 string pass="password";
string email="example@example.com";
 webControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('email').value="+email);
 webControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('pass').value="+pass);
 webControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementsByName('u_0_1').click()");
```

but its not working can anyone figure this out

Comment: can i get the javascript for autofilling?

Answer (score 1):

Your setting the same email field twice. Try...

```
webControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('email').value="+email);
webControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('pass').value="+password)
webControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('u_0_n').click()");
```

I'm not sure if `password` is the correct id, you'll have to inspect the element yourself.

Comment: sorry it was a typing mistake actually i have done it right but iam not able to fill anything can you provide me the javascript alone for this filling purpose

Comment: its working the problem is that facbook wont allow the users to inject javascripts

Comment: What do you mean "wont allow"? It works for me. But of course the "u_0_n" id is not static, it changes, so you need to get the button using some other approach. The easiest one probably is `webControl1.ExecuteJavascript("document.getElementById('pass').form.submit()");`